# How to maintain single try catch block in ios App

Tags: ios, try-catch

I have 10 Classes in my project,At present i was placing try catch block in each and every method in all 10 classes  to catch the exception which seems to be a bulky code.

Now i want to maintain a Single try catch block through out the project, means if any exception occurred in  all my 10 classes that should be catched by try catch block.

Is it possible to do like this…

```
 NSArray *arr=[[d1 objectForKey:@"Time"] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
 NSArray *arr1=[[arr objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```

Here my object “Time” is coming from the Service.
so if the object is empty it may cause to
Array out of index Exception.
I know which i can solve by comparing the length of String.So, if suppose if forgot to compare length in some cases.
In that case i want to catch the exception and i want to post it to my server.

```
  @catch (NSException *exception) {

    NSString *stacktrace=[exception.reason stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];

    stacktrace=[stacktrace stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];


   // NSString *strClass = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
   NSString *strClass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@",NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
    Item* myStore = [Item sharedStore];
    myStore.strErrorDescription=exception.name;
    myStore.strErrorStack=stacktrace;
    myStore.strErrorPageName=strClass;  
      [myStore PostError];// To Post the exception to My server.
        ErrorView *errorView=[[ErrorView alloc]initWithNibName:@"ErrorView" bundle:nil];  [self presentViewController: errorView  animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you are using try-catch blocks properly? They are used in iOS programming but very rarely and I still have yet to ever write one in Objective-C.

Comment: You can do it, but if you're just debugging code, you probably just want to turn on an Exception Breakpoint.

Comment: @DBoyer thanks for reply.is that is not the good way to use try catch blocks

Comment: Show an example or two and explain why you are using try/catch. It should be a very rare thing, not common.

Comment: @AaronBrager  NO, my intention to post the crash repeort to my server and not for debugging

Comment: @siva Don't post a link to an external file. Update your question with the sample code. And if your goal is to be able to generate crash reports that can be sent to you, then you don't want any try/catch. Integrate a tool such as PLCrashReporter.

Comment: @rmaddy Once see my update,i will have a look at PLCrashReporter.My inetention is to not only post the error to my server,when exception occured i want to redirect to some other view contoller instaed of closing the App

Comment: In the code you posted, there is no reason at all to get an exception. Instead, add some simple `if` statements to ensure `arr` and `arr1` have the expected number of elements. Never make such assumptions and never use try/catch for something that can so easily be dealt with properly.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer here is You're Doing It Wrong.

Exceptions in Objective-C are different from those in other languages like Java or Ruby. In particular, they tend to be "non-recoverable", meaning that once some code throws an exception, a number of assumptions about the state of memory allocations, etc become false, and your program is probably on its way to crashing.

The overall approach [Apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH9-SW3) is to treat exceptions as a symptom of a programmer error. The example you give is the same one they do: neglecting to check the length of an NSArray. You should aim to find and eliminate those during your development process; the best way to do that is probably to let your program crash as a result of the exception, then find and fix the offending code.

Comment: then how can i Show some other view to the user when crash occurs, is it not possoble /

Comment: This is a pretty good read if you want more detail: http://club15cc.com/code/objective-c/dispelling-nsexception-myths-in-ios-can-we-use-try-catch-finally

Comment: Aaron, interesting article, thanks! I guess I'm just spreading the dogma. :) Although the fact that Swift doesn't have an exception mechanism is an indicator of Apple's thoughts here.